# How to force cache to be reused after app restart - GeckoFX / xulRunner

Tags: caching, xulrunner, http-caching, geckofx, embedded-browser

I'm new to embedded browsers, I admit, but I've got a GeckoFX v33 control working and hosted in a WPF application. Browsing and caching is working during a browsing **session**. However, upon application **restart** the cache is lost (or ignored) and all web assets are re-downloaded!

I'm quite dumbfounded why this isn't enabled by default, as it is a web browser control after all.

I've tried setting a custom profile path to an existing directory with write access:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xulrunner");
Gecko.Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "webcache");
Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(path);
```

I've also tried setting various combinations of preferences i.e.

```
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User.SetBoolPref("browser.cache.disk.enable",true);                
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User.SetIntPref("Browser.cache.disk.capacity", 50000);
```

However, it ALWAYS loads the web assets again on app restart!

**Does anyone know the correct configuration to get geckoFX or xulRunner to look at the last cache on startup?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have narrowed down this bug to the **geckofx-33.0 version**.

Downgrading to **geckofx-31.0-01 or lower** fixed my problem and the cache is persisted (in the */cache2* folder, created automatically).

I tested the following combinations (OS: Windows):

> - GeckoFx 29.0-015.zip with xulRunner 29.0.1.en-US.win32.zip: Disk    caching WORKS!
> - GeckoFx 31.0-01.zip with xulRunner 31.0.en-US.win32.zip: Disk caching    WORKS!
> - GeckoFx 33.0-02.zip with xulRunner 33.0.2.en-US.win32.zip: Disk    caching **FAILS**!

I was using the 33 version above (as it was the latest version!) and hence could not get disk caching to work. I definitely think this is a bug, as it is reproducible each time. I don't know if the bug lies in geckoFx or the xulRunner runtime, but I'll leave this up to the developers brains-trust to fix. I believe the cache API changed in v33.

So, for now I guess I'll just fallback to version 31 and wait for a fix.